# Prevent logout auth laravel

Tags: php, laravel

is there any way to listen the logout event and take decisions like redirect on auth laravel? I know there are some login/logout listeners but redirects are not working:

```
class LogSuccessfulLogout
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Logout  $event
     * @return void
     */
   public function handle(Logout $event)
   {
    if($event->user) {


        $new = Auth::user()->cars()->where('status', 1)->count();
        $inProgress = Auth::user()->cars()->where('status', 2)->count();

        if($new > 0 || $inProgress > 0){
            redirect('/');
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default logout function called in in the default Laravel 5.2 AuthController

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->logout();
    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
}
```

You can therefore set the `redirectAfterLogout` property to change the redirect url with the following code in your AuthController,

```
private $redirectAfterLogout = '/new-logout-redirect';
```

or you can choose to simply override the logout function.
Redirects will not work directly from your Listener.

Here's the modified logout function with your logic which you can place in your AuthController,

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->logout();

    $new = Auth::user()->cars()->where('status', 1)->count();
    $inProgress = Auth::user()->cars()->where('status', 2)->count();

    if($new > 0 || $inProgress > 0){
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I need some logic and to not logout `if($new > 0 || $inProgress > 0)`, so I can't do this from listener? So if that condition is true do not logout and redirect to home.

Comment: Not directly. (Maybe you could work out a hack like handle an exception or something similar, but that beats the whole point of a separate Listener). To add logic, you can override the logout function in your AuthController. I'll update the answer with your logic.